# How to auto reconnect the DB when the DB is restarted/disconnected which is deployed as java jar application in openshift?

Tags: java

i have java jar application that gets loaded only once. It works fine until the DB goes down. Once the DB is up, it is not able to refresh the connection. If I restart the JAR it is working fine. How do I refresh the connection once DB is restarted without restarting the application..

Comment: Show us the connection code, please...

Comment: Initial thoughts are to enter some while loop when a boolean is set true that is caught by your connection try/catch. Then you could thread.sleep() and retry the connection every so often until you re-connect and break the "try re-connect loop"